# Metadata version mismatch for module... angular-flash-messages, any solution for this

Tags: angularjs, flash-message

**ERROR in Error**: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/angular2-flash-messages/module/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/src/app/app.module.ts
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1597:31)
    at new SyntaxError (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1795:20)
    at simplifyInContext (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25774:27)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25786:17)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25282:64)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:126:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:101:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:52:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:78:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:241:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/Users/ip/Sites/SmartShoeApp/angular-src/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:495:24)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

**OS:** mac OS high sierra

**package.json:**

{
  "name": "meanauthapp",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "mean stack application",

"main": "app.js",

"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",

```
"start": "node app"
```

},

"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",

```
"mongoose": "*",

"bcryptjs": "*",

"cors": "*",

"jsonwebtoken": "*",

"body-parser": "*",

"passport": "*",

"passport-jwt": "*"
```

},

"author": "ip",

"license": "ISC",

"devDependencies": {

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.5"
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it today on my angular4 app.
I've set 1.0.8 version in package.json and it works for me now:

```
"angular2-flash-messages": "1.0.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.5" in package.json file.